# Can't DatePicker change Text#YearText

Tags: c#, text, datepicker, avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to change the Year label of the `DatePicker` element.
How do I change the text in the "Year" field?

There is a `DatePicker` element.

The element has a method `protected override void OnApplyTemplate(TemplateAppliedEventArgs e)`.

In this method there is `_yearText = e.NameScope.Find<TextBlock>("YearText");`

As I understand it, you need to pass a template with a name to this element:

```
<Style Selector="DatePicker">
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="YearText"
                        Text="!!HelloYear!!" />
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

But such a construction causes an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to change that text. According to the [documentation](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/troubleshooting#locally-set-properties-override-styles):

> Some default Avalonia styles use local values in their templates
> instead of template bindings or styles-setters, which makes it
> impossible to update template property without replacing whole
> template.

...and this is one of those cases.

For example, this is how you could change the foreground or tooltip of this text block:

```
<Style Selector="DatePicker /template/ Button TextBlock:nth-child(3)">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip.Tip" Value="update"/>
</Style>
```

But it won't work in the case of `Text` property, because it is manually set to `year` [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Controls/DatePicker.xaml#L110).

So the only way to go is to override the entire [template](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Controls/DatePicker.xaml#L82) and since this control uses static resources you might have to copy them as well.